# Add Page Tab Dialog, a ReferenceError is raised on Facebook code - "ua is not defined"

Tags: facebook, exception, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am launching the Add Page Tab Dialog using the `FB.ui` method of the Javascript API:

```
FB.ui({method: 'pagetab'},function(response){
    // code that records the page(s) selected removed 
});
```

If I don't have the console open in my browser, the dialog pops up, but the progress icon spins indefinitely. If I do have the console open, I see that a `ReferenceError` exception is being thrown with the message "ua is not defined." `ua` appears to be an instance of an object that should be part of Facebook's pagetab code. The enclosing functions are also marked with `_DEPRECATED`, which is a bit worrisome.

This code has worked fine up until yesterday, but I don't see anything in the Facebook Developer blog about changes that could impact the Add Page Tab Dialog.

The error: (click for larger, more readable version)

[image: ReferenceError: "ua is not defined"]

User-facing behavior:

[image: empty Add Page Tab dialog]

Update: this is now a [known Facebook bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/197557357034879?browse=search_51673a317b5092124734169).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in the Facebook API. They pushed out a fix today which returns the Add Page Tab dialog to operational status.